# How are supernatural traits inherited in "Buffy the Vampire Slayer"?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer, demons, genetics

All demons in *Buffy* are part human, and therefore capable of interbreeding. So what happens when they do?

For instance, would the child of a bracken demon and a polgara have face spikes *and* big arm spikes? How are supernatural traits inherited?

Are there any instances in the show (or Angel) where two demon species reproduce?

Comment: I'm willing to agree that all (most) demons are *humanoid,* but that doesn't necessarily mean they're "part human."  Lorne's species, for example, comes from a parallel dimension, despite *looking like* humans with green skin.  Interbreeding might be possible between some species (one or two species do it on screen), but what evidence do we have that all or even most can do so?

Comment: Just as an aside Brachen demons do not have retractable face spikes Doyle had a human form and a demon form his spike were always present in his demon form they only gave the appearance of being retractable because he could switch forms at will

Comment: @revenant good point, edited

Comment: @Steve-O it's actually canon that all of the "demon" species are part human - the result of the Old Ones breeding with humans before they were banished.

Comment: @Benubird Good find.  I didn't recall that detail myself.

Comment: Possibly except for vampires.  In addition to the Angel/Angelus divide, there were a couple times that they said vampires inhabited the body of the human victim.  And while there's a couple conflicting origins, one of them seems to imply that one of the Old One's blood is an infection that vampires spread - they weren't created the same way as the other human-breed demons.

Comment: @Izkata Quite right. But can vampires reproduce sexually? My understanding is that since they inhabit a corpse, they can't have children - hence the big deal with connor. I wonder if a vampire can turn a demon? That would probably be the equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Not all demons were part human only demons native to our dimension I am not entirely certain if there is a canonical list of which demons were native though.

Not all demons were capable of hybridization with humans, most instances of demonic reproduction we see someone or something is about to die a horrible horrible death when a fully demon creature rips its way from their body, or they were going to be eaten after being used to fertilize eggs.

It is likely that different species of demons cannot hybridize even if they both have human blood does not mean their demon blood would mix as far as I know there are no demon/demon hybrids depicted in either show

EDIT:  Each half demon we see is a somewhat unique individual so we have no way to compare how their demonic traits are normally passed it is also important to note in the real world hybrid expression can change depending on the gestating species.  A quote from the buffy wiki "A half-demon would be something entirely new in each case" is probably the closest one could get to an answer.

Comment: Yes, but I'm only asking about the ones that can interbreed. We see examples in the show of part-human demons, and if two species can hybridize with humans, then they can with each other.

Comment: With real world genetics that would stand but with supernatural genetics it is not necessarily true.  It is also important to note that DNA transfer may not play any role in half-breeds Cordelia was made into a half demon through some form of essence bonding or transfer.  There really is no way to answer the question in canon.

Comment: Note that the slayer line was also created by bonding with a demon, but Buffy is never referred to as a demon or half-demon herself. Maybe it's a semantic thing, just calling cordelia "half-demon" because "human partially possessed by bonding with a demonic spirit capable of transferring supernatural attributes" was a bit long for everyday conversation... :p